# How to update MongoDb database in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, web-applications

I'm newbie with the MongoDb, there are a lot of examples about updating a collection in 2.x versions but I couldn't find any source about 3.x versions.

JAVA CODE:

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbTest");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection =    database.getCollection("colTest");
    Document updateQuery = new Document();
    updateQuery.append("$set",
    new Document().append("_id", "test"));
    Document searchQuery = new Document();
    searchQuery.append("likes", "125");
    collection.updateMulti(searchQuery, updateQuery); //.updateMulti gives an error.
```

There isn't any updateMulti in 3.x so how can I check the id of the database and change one of the datas?

Example MongoDB:

```
 { 
"_id" : "test",
   "status" : 2,
   "time" : null,
   "instagram" :{
         "description" : "database",
         "likes" : 100,
         "url" : "http://www.instagram.com/",
         "by", "users"
   },
   "batchid" : 15000234
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{ 
   "_id" : "test",
   "status" : 1,
   "time" : null,
   "instagram" :{
         "description" : "database",
         "likes" : 125,
         "url" : "http://www.instagram.com/",
         "by", "users"
   },
   "batchid" : 15000234
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mongodb-java driver:

Use updateOne method
            To update single Document within the collection based on the filter,

```
         collection.updateOne(searchQuery, updateQuery );
```

Use updateMany method,
             To Update multiple Documents within the collection based on the filter ,

```
         collection.updateMany(searchQuery, updateQuery );
```

Example,

```
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("TestDB");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("test");
        Document query = new Document();
        query.append("_id","test");
        Document setData = new Document();
        setData.append("status", 1).append("instagram.likes", 125);
        Document update = new Document();
        update.append("$set", setData);
        //To update single Document  
        collection.updateOne(query, update);
```

Answer (score 0):

so i wrote this function

```
 public void SetValueFromDB(String collectionName, String id, String id_value, String fieldOfChange, Object changToValue) {
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
            searchQuery.append(id, id_value);
            Document setData = new Document();
            setData.append(fieldOfChange, changToValue);
            Document updateQuery = new Document();
            updateQuery.append("$set", setData);
            collection.updateOne(searchQuery, updateQuery);
    }
```

so for use it

```
db.SetValueFromDB("MyCollection","_id","test","likes",150);
```