# Update multiple fields -Partial update- in MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document like below in mongo database and I have corresponding Model class Flight.java with all possible fields that are come in any time as update ?

```
{
    "flight": {
        "event": "Leg",
        "version": "2",
        "key": {
            "fltNum": "1111",
            "fltOrgDate": "2021-01-12",
            "depSta": "BBB",
            "dupDepStaNum": "0"
        },
        "leg": {
            "stations": {
                "arr": "VVV",
                "dupArrStaNum": "0"
            },
            "times": {
                "STD": "2021-01-12T20:30:00",
                "STA": "2021-01-12T23:21:00",
                "LTD": "2021-01-12T20:30:00",
                "LTA": "2021-01-12T23:05:00",
                "PTA": "2021-01-12T23:05:00"
            },
            "status": {
                "leg": " ",
                "dep": "S",
                "arr": "S"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I will get updates for this document continuously with existing fields or some new fields also. I am not sure which filed will get update.

So How can I update document using java MongoDB or Spring Data MongoDB?

Comment: Could you approve the answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have pojo which has all possible fields.

Every update requires three parts.

1. Find command to identify the doc to be updated
2. Doc which specifies what will be updated
3. Options specifies upsert, multi

You can iterate each fields in pojo and check for not null fields then add it to updateDoc

[example update in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433341/how-to-update-mongodb-database-in-java/42435046)